# Get particular layout javascript and css

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Currently I am trying to get the "checkout_onepage_index" layout css and javascript in another page. How Can i get the javascript and css in a controller or observer. I want to get all the css and javascript that was loaded in checkout_onepage_index layout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much using observer but you can defiantly do this using xml just copu your checkout.xml js code and paste it into another file of xml like "catalog.xml".